# Can't get percentage on distict count

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table as shown below.I want to calculate the percentage of people who received 365_training bare in mind EMP_ID 1233 has two role HT and BCL and the 365 training is counted twice where i just want to get the percentage based on the distinct EMP_ID. ANy help on this would be greatly appriciated.

[image: HI , I have]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just be a ratio like this:

```
PercentEmyTrained =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[EMP_ID] ),
        Table1[Training_365_Received] = "yes"
    ),
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[EMP_ID] )
)
```

Comment: You are a genius bro. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a column:

```
Perc = 
var empID = yourTable[EMP_ID]
return COUNTROWS(FILTER(yourTable;empID = yourTable[EMP_ID] && yourTable[Training_356_Received]))/ COUNTROWS(yourTable))
```

Also make the column of type %. It counts the rows where EMP_ID are equal and he training is done and divides this by count of rows.

Comment: Thanks Aldert. I was trying to do it in measure instead of coumn, but both ways it works. Much appriciated your help borther.